# Using an expression and an equation to get an ODE to describe something.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, applications

I have an expression and an equation, that I need to use to show that ODE describes something.

Let me put it into **context**

> I have an expression for the Rate at Anti-Freeze flows $\mathcal{IN}$
> and $\mathcal{OUT}$ of an compartment:
>
> $$\dfrac{dA}{dt}=\bigg[C_{in}Q_{in}-\bigg(\frac{AQ_{out}}{V_{tot}}\bigg)\bigg]$$
>
> and I also have an equation to show concentration  $$C =\frac{A}{V_{tot}}$$
>
> and I need to use these two, to show the ODE describing Concentration
> of Anti-Freeze in the compartment, $C(t)$, is
>
> $$[V_o\space+ (Q_{in}-Q_{out})t ]\dfrac{dC}{dt}\space+ Q_{in}C =Q_{in}C_{in}$$

Any help would be grateful. Any questions about the problem I am happy to answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perhaps check out the definitions of volumetric flow rate (Q), if you are not familiar with it.
Also it seems like there is an assumption on the $Q_{in}$ and $Q_{out}$ missing - they are constant (?). That will make the following sort out nicely:

$$
Q_{tot} = Q_{in} - Q_{out} = \dot{V}_{tot} \\
\Rightarrow V_{tot}= V_0 + t(Q_{in} - Q_{out})
$$
(simply integrate $V_{tot}$, which is simple when the VFR's are constant)

Let's rewrite the compartment concentration to $C V_{tot} = A$.
If you differentiate this (product rule), and inserting the above, you get

$$
\dot{C} V_{tot} + C \dot{V}_{tot} = \dot{A}  \Rightarrow \dot{C}(V_0 + t(Q_{in} - Q_{out})) + C (Q_{in} - Q_{out}) = \dot{A} = C_{in} Q_{in} - C Q_{out}
$$
(last equality is from the first differential equation you had). Then simply move one term to the other side and you are there.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!